# Find the volume of solid generated by rotating this sector?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the plane region bounded from upward by circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and from downward by two straight lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$ around $x-axis$

So as I read this the question, I imagined he's asking me to draw a circle whose radius is 2, and then 2 lines making a sector in that circle and then revolve that sector around x-axis. I had 3 attempts at this and all 3 gave different answers.

**First attempt**, the original Calculus attempt (the problem is in a Calculus textbook):
$$\pi \left(\int _{-2}^0\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}+x\right)^2dx\:+\:\int _0^2\left(\sqrt{4-x^2}-x\right)^2dx\:\:\right) = \frac{16\pi}{3}$$
I suspected this answer because I tried rotating the whole circle and found that the volume of the sphere was $\frac{32\pi}{3}$ which made me confused because I don't know if the rotated sector can have half the volume of the rotated sphere.

**Second attempt**, tried using some basic geometry:

We know that the two lines forming the sector are $y = x$ and $y = -x$, so it's pretty obvious that the angle between each one and the $x-axis$ is $45$ degrees, therefore the angle between the two lines is $90$ degrees. Which is again obvious since one is only the negative of the other.
I googled the formula of the Area of Sector and it was $(\frac{\theta}{2})*r^2$, andI know the volume of any regular shape is $V = Area*h$ I didn't know whether to use the radius as the height or the height of sector so I tried both, and they evaluated to $V = 2\pi$ and $V \approx 1.8$

I suspected this one was wrong because the values are too small?

**Third attempt**, I simply calculated the total volume of sphere and divided by 4 knowing the sector is a quarter-circle:

$V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$, $ V = \frac{4}{3} \pi *(2)^3 = \frac{32\pi}{3}, V of sector = \frac{\frac{32\pi}{3}}{4} = \frac{8\pi}{3}$

this caught my attention because it was exactly the half of the first answer.
But honestly, after these attempts all with different answers I just think I am completely wrong with the three of them at this point. I hope someone clears up why I am wrong, if I am.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the diagram below the exercise is to find the volume of the solid of revolution when revolving the blue region about the $x$-axis.

If one varies $x$ between the values of $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ and uses the annulus method then

\begin{eqnarray}
V&=&\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\pi(R^2-r^2)\,dx\\
&=&2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}R^2-r^2\,dx\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

where $R=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $r=x$. This gives a value

\begin{equation}
V=\frac{16\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}
\end{equation}

As a check we can also find the volume of the solid of revolution formed by revolving the red region about the $x$-axis. The blue plus red volumes should sum to the volume $V=\dfrac{32\pi}{3}$.

The "red volume" can be found by the cylindrical shell method. We will use the sector on the right and double the result so that

\begin{equation}
V=2\int_0^\sqrt{2}2\pi rh\,dy
\end{equation}

where $r=y$ and $h=\sqrt{4-y^2}-y$. So

\begin{equation}
V=4\pi\int_0^\sqrt{2}y\sqrt{4-y^2}-y^2\,dy
\end{equation}

which has a value of

\begin{equation}
V=\frac{32\pi}{3}-\frac{16\sqrt{2}\pi}{3}
\end{equation}

And we see that the "blue volume" and "red volume" sum correctly to the volume of the sphere.

**Addendum:** Note that if one integrates equation $(1)$ over the range $[-2,2]$ that will give the volume of the solid of revolution formed by revolving both the **green** and the blue regions (with the green volume subtracted from the blue volume), which is not the volume asked for in the question.

[image: Solid of revolution]

Comment: Why the $sqrt(2)$? I thought the limits of the integral would only be $-2,2$ since the radius is $sqrt(4) = 2$? I plugged $2$ instead of $sqrt(2)$ in your solution and it gave my first answer, $\frac{16\pi}{3}$.

Comment: The limits of the integral over the blue region extend from the smallest to the largest $x$ coordinate of points in the blue region. This occurs at the points where the graphs $y=-x$ and $y=x$ intersect the circle. The $x$-coordinates of those points are $\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I have modified the graph and added additional information to explain why it is incorrect to integrate from $-2$ to $+2$. I hope this helps you to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I remember the formula with factor $\dfrac23\cdot R$ as position of CG from center. Even if forgotten, it can be always found by integration. The semi vertical angle (at apex ) is $\;\alpha$.

$$ \bar{y}= \frac23 \cdot R\cdot \frac{\sin \alpha}{\alpha}$$

I also like to retain symbolic form till the last step.

Distance travelled by CG

$$ 2\pi \bar{y}$$

Area of sector

$$ \alpha R^2$$

Multiply the above to get revolved Volume by Pappu's theorem.

$$V= \sin \alpha \cdot \dfrac{4 \pi R^3}{3}$$

Correctly checks standard sphere volume for $ \alpha = \pi/2$

Plug in present case values $R=2, \alpha = \pi/4$

$$ V=\dfrac{16 \sqrt 2 \pi}{3}$$

***Suppose*** we are asked to choose $\alpha$ that bisects volume this way, readily... $ \alpha = \pi/6.$